# Problems in integration(trigonometry)

Tags: integration

How would you integrate $tan^3 x/cos^2x$ ? I've thinking to convert $tan^3 x$ to ratio form but i have found myself in a dilemma,how would you tackle this kind of question?

Comment: Hint:  write your integrand as $sin^3(x)cos^{-5}(x)=sin(x)(1-cos^2(x))cos^{-5}(x)$

Comment: Try $x=\tan^{-1}(t)$

Comment: Do you mean you are looking for an antiderivative?

Comment: @JeanMarie yes i surely am

Comment: Hint: 
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\tan^n x = n \tan^{n-1} x  \tan' x $$
$$= n \tan^{n-1}x (1+\tan^2 x) =
n \tan^{n-1}x \left(1+\frac{\sin^2 x }{\cos^2 x }\right)$$
$$ =
n \tan^{n-1} x \left(\frac{\cos^2 x +\sin^2 x }{\cos^2 x }\right) =
n \frac{\tan^{n-1} x }{\cos^2 x } $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that $\;\int f(x)\,dx = F(x)\;$ , then $\;\int g'(x)\,f(g(x))\,dx=F(g(x))\;$ .

Apply this now to $\;f(x)=\tan x\implies f'(x)=\frac1{\cos^2x}\;$ , so

$$\int\frac1{\cos^2x}\tan^3x\,dx=\frac14\tan^4x +C$$

since we know $\;\int x^m\,dx=\frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}+C\;$